# Passing in an array for a Ruby Class

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following code:

```
class MyGreeting  
def initialize(name)  
    # Instance variables  
    @name = name
end  

def say_hello  
    name.each do |x|
    puts "Hello #{x}" 
end 
def say_bye  
    name.each do |x|
    puts "Bye #{x}" 
end  
end

obj = MyGreeting.new([“johnny”, “kyle”, “sid”])
obj.say_hello
```

I am trying to make a class called MyGreeter that receives an array of values that are then used in the class. In the code above, I kinda show what I'm going for.  I am trying to have the method say_hello output "hello johnny" "hello kyle" hello sid" when used.  Right now I am getting an error that I cannot resolve.  Any assistance is appreciated.

This is the error i'm receiving
      `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: Please edit to identify the line on which the syntax error occurred. A couple of problems: 1. `name.each do |x|` does not have a matching `end`. 2. `name` is an uninitialized local variable in `say_hello` and `say_bye`. You probably want `@name`.

Comment: Done, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Cary Swoveland says above, you need `end`s to go with your `do`s. You also need to change `name` to `@name` in the `say_` methods.

Here's a working version:

```
class MyGreeting  
  def initialize(name)  
    # Instance variables  
    @name = name
  end  

  def say_hello  
    @name.each do |x|
      puts "Hello #{x}" 
    end
  end 

  def say_bye  
    @name.each do |x|
      puts "Bye #{x}" 
    end
  end  
end

obj = MyGreeting.new(["johnny", "kyle", "sid"])
obj.say_hello
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems here, but the biggest one is that your indentation is completely out of control and needs to be addressed. It's extremely important to keep your code clean and orderly so you can spot mistakes at a glance and so the structure is apparent to anyone working on it. Fixing the indentation shows immediately that there's a lot of missing `end` statements.

Secondly you've got “smart quotes” in there which Ruby cannot deal with. If you're not using a proper code editor you may have to turn those off.

Thirdly, you forgot to declare `name` as a property which is necessary if you want to refer to it without the `@` prefix.

All that and you get this:

```
class MyGreeting  
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)  
    # Instance variables  
    @name = name
  end  

  def say_hello  
    name.each do |x|
      puts "Hello #{x}" 
    end
  end

  def say_bye  
    name.each do |x|
      puts "Bye #{x}"
    end
  end
end

obj = MyGreeting.new(["johnny", "kyle", "sid"])
obj.say_hello
```

As a style note, if a variable implicitly contains more than one thing give it a name that implies that, like `names` here would be a better choice.

Comment: You forgot to change name to @name.

Comment: So it does! :-) It did seem odd that you'd overlook that.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, proper indentation will reveal the problem of not ending the block with the `end`.

After fixing the indentation, we get the following error:

```
`say_hello': undefined local variable or method `name' for #<MyGreeting:0x007f940c03ba90 @name=["johnny", "kyle", "sid"]> (NameError)
Did you mean?  @name
```

This shows that the `name` you are using in the following piece of code

```
name.each do |x|
  #...
end
```

is "undefined" and ruby thinks it is either a local variable or a method.
Obviously you intend it to be the `@name` instance variable, so you can prefix the `name` with `@`, as pointed out by [nc.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44637/nc).

Another solution is to use the "getter method" for the `@name` instance variable by adding `attr_reader` method, as [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) suggests.

```
class MyGreeting
  attr_reader :name
  # ...rest of the code omitted for brevity
end
```

Note that `attr_reader :name` is actually a method (along with its argument) and this is the same as:

```
def name
  @name
end
```

This is the "getter method" (which is an instance method for the `MyGreeting` object) for the `@name` instance variable in that we an get the data (`@name`) stored in the object (`obj`) by calling this method.

If you implement either of these (i.e. if you add `attr_reader :name` or

```
def name
  @name
end
```

), you don't need to add `@` before the `name` since the `name` itself is actually a method which, when called, returns `@name`.

Hope this gives you a better idea of how the value of an instance variable  is referenced in Ruby.

---

As a side note, you can turn an array to a method's argument list with '*', or ["splat operator"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion). It works as follows:

```
def demo(arguments)
  puts "arguments: #{arguments}"
end

demo(["foo", "bar"]) #=> arguments: ["foo", "bar"]

def demo_2(*arguments)
  puts "arguments: #{arguments}"
end

demo_2("foo", "bar") #=> arguments: ["foo", "bar"]
```

Note, in `demo_2`, we are just passing in string objects, which will then be turned into an array using the [* (splat) operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion). This is especially useful when you don't know how many arguments you want to pass on to a method, in which case passing an array of object will not work since its size is fixed.

---

Incorporating all the points discussed above, your original code could be refactored as follows:

```
class MyGreeting
  attr_reader :names

  def initialize(*names)
    @names = names
  end

  def say_hello  
    names.each do |name|
      puts "Hello #{name}" 
    end
  end 

  def say_bye  
    names.each do |name|
      puts "Bye #{name}" 
    end
  end
end


obj = MyGreeting.new("johnny", "kyle", "sid")
obj.say_hello

## output:
# Hello johnny
# Hello kyle
# Hello sid
```